# routing error - Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Type<any>'

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Unable to resolve this problem, whenever I tried to use this routing method it showing error like

Type '{ path: string; component: typeof TrendsComponent; }' is not assignable to type 'Route'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'path' does not exist in type 'Route'.

```
export const MODULE_ROUTES: Route[] = [
  { path: 'trends', component: TrendsComponent },
  { path: 'customtrend', component: CustomtrendComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'trends', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you are using Route from angular/compiler/src/core (`import { Route } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';`), it's not correct.

You can use Route[] as well, but make sure that Route is imported like this `import {  Route } from '@angular/router';`

Happy coding!

Comment: I always have problem with auto import :D especially for EventEmitter :D

Answer (score 3):

Change 'Route[]' to 'Routes', 'Routes' is already an array of objects type. 

And 'Routes' should be imported in this way: import { Routes } from '@angular/router'.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **`[]`** next to Route , Change

**From**

```
export const MODULE_ROUTES: Route[]
```

**To**

```
export const MODULE_ROUTES: Route
```